# Paypal button integration problem

Tags: php, paypal

I am using PayPal button in my website but after successful transaction I am returned back to my website and I got response like

```
**'http://172.16.1.55/sfl/paymentsucc/?auth=sKBXUgClgCNkCRcZGcK_LvICi6PAj2k261b0oDK-EQZZsibuvP6xSI4QK1i2q88jUDP_AFFaHWUlCsWM93xs-E66jNQ33z_u-Y8KzSOWIKN0O44oIa6Xj-JIvtgCCAFB_NONaHVNjIKzD1dzfp6Rm9s6clVOj70Ikk7F5-e8zmY5DgRmmuISLRw08nEOUj92psDXMvfuKmB7Tbm_gygUABJqTV0oz5KWrgNINj02vuXn7AH-XseAbYRfRoS&form_charset=UTF-8'**
```

I don't understand how to decode this auth response using PHP. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: This is not a PayPal response. Please add additional information regarding your full checkout flow, including the API calls you're making and what the full error is. What you're showing us is not an error; it's a link. Albeit a long one.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked out the PayPal API information?

Here is a useful link to that https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_documentation

Also if you goto https://developer.paypal.com and login/signup then you will be able to check more information out there.

Hope this helps